# Preference list context menu / longclick - implement

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a context menu. I have a preference list that I can get the view and ID of each item in the pref list but, for the life of me , I can not get my context menu to come up. When I longclick on a pref item I can Toast its ID and view. Where should I put the onCreateContextMenu and the onContextItemSelected to get my menu to come up? I commented out registerForContextMenu(view); because I was still able to Toast the view and ID without it. Any help would be great!

```
public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

   ListView listView = getListView();
   listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     ListView listView = (ListView) parent;
     ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
     Object obj = listAdapter.getItem(position);
     if (obj != null && obj instanceof View.OnLongClickListener) {
       View.OnLongClickListener longListener = (View.OnLongClickListener) obj;

       return longListener.onLongClick(view);
     } else {
       Preference pref = (Preference) obj;
       // prefs
       makeToast("pref toast - " + id + view);
       //registerForContextMenu(view);
       //onCreateContextMenu(R.menu.context_menu, view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo);
     }
      return true;
    }
    });
}

public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
  // long click
  //registerForContextMenu(v);
 return true;
}

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    MenuInflater inflateLayout = getMenuInflater();
    inflateLayout.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            makeToast("mmm 1 slice");
            break;
        case R.id.item2:
            makeToast("mmm 2 slices");
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void makeToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `registerForContextMenu()` on a View, you do *not* need to set an `OnLongClickListener` for that View. So, you've got all the right code, you've just got some extra stuff that's getting in the way. Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

        ListView listView = getListView();
        registerForContextMenu(listView);       
    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflateLayout = getMenuInflater();
        inflateLayout.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.item1:
                makeToast("mmm 1 slice"); 
                break;
            case R.id.item2:
                makeToast("mmm 2 slices");
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void makeToast(String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```